# Windows Forms with Entity Framework crashes on .theninclude() only on published version, not in debug

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Issue: I think the title sums it up, but in more detail, I'm trying to use Entity Framework in a Windows Forms application. It works for all "selects" but not when I try to use `.ThenInclude()` and to make it even more weird, it only crashes on the published version of it. When I'm debugging, it works perfectly fine. Once I publish it, it crashes on the `.ThenInclude()`

The error code is the following:

> DeepLoadProjects The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\KD9YXEPJ.DKY\5QCR3OCQ.WRY\vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2\x86\SNI.dll
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()

Here's the method that is crashing ONLY ON PUBLISHED:

```
public Tprojects DeepLoadProject(int intProjectID)
{
    Tprojects objTiers = new Tprojects();

    try
    {
        RefreshAll();
        objTiers = context.Tprojects
                          .Include(x => x.TprojectItems)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.IntItem)
                          .Include(x => x.TprojectCustomerCompanies)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.IntCustomerCompany)
                          .Include(x => x.TprojectCustomerCompanies)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.TprojectCustomerCompanyContacts)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.IntContact)
                          .Include(x => x.TprojectItems)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.TprojectItemCompanyPrices)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.IntProjectCustomerCompany)
                          .Where(x => x.IntProjectId == intProjectID)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Show("There was an issue trying to connect to the server, please try again. If this error keeps showing please call an admin for further assistance.");
        SaveErrorLog("DeepLoadProjects " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException, "Hollywood");
    }

    return objTiers;
}
```

Here's my assembly info and the full error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\KD9YXEPJ.DKY\5QCR3OCQ.WRY\vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2\x86\SNI.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Vents_US_Inventory.modDatabaseUtilities.DeepLoadProject(Int32 intProjectID)
   at Vents_US_Inventory.CRMS_Forms.Projects.ProjectInfo.LoadProjectInfo()
   at Vents_US_Inventory.CRMS_Forms.Projects.ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Vents-US Inventory
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Vents-US%20Inventory.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4550.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36309
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DLL
----------------------------------------
netstandard
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/netstandard/v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51/netstandard.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.20.21406
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36309
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36309
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36309
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ValueTuple
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ValueTuple/v4.0_4.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51/System.ValueTuple.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
    Assembly Version: 4.0.5.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.20.21406
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Options
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DLL
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
    Assembly Version: 4.2.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.20.56604
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Immutable
    Assembly Version: 1.2.5.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.20.21406
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/System.Collections.Immutable.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 3.1.28.0
    Win32 Version: 3.100.2822.36305
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
    Assembly Version: 1.13.20136.2
    Win32 Version: 1.13.20136.2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Scott/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KD9YXEPJ.DKY/5QCR3OCQ.WRY/vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.DLL
----------------------------------------
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this issue for far too long.

Thanks!

Comment: there's some assembly missing. try to include all assemblies before you publish the application. or try to copy all DLLs in the bin folder of the solution and paste them into the directory where the application has been deployed.

Comment: @odaiwa where is the directory where I need to put it if it's been installed on the C drive? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You need to find where the installer saves the application data on your disc and paste the DLLs there.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it does that for me? I can't do that for each computer I'm installing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here is what seems to be the issue https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/936.

I found a not so great workaround, but it consistently works, so I guess it's not all that bad.

Here's my workaround until they come up with a fix or show me what I did wrong.

> The only way I can get it to work is on each device after install, to manually copy and paste the x64 and x86 folders with SNI inside it from the debug in the project files to the application folder "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\KD9YXEPJ.DKY\5QCR3OCQ.WRY\vent..tion_098ef6a925fa6387_0001.0009_35951381a6b516d2" for each machine.

for the record, I'm still looking for a better answer :)